# Is there a way to minimize all of the windows on just my primary display in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, desktop

On my work computer, running Windows 7, I typically have one monitor displaying for the main computer and the other largely dedicated to a remote desktop connection. A common occurrence for me is needing to access the desktop on the primary screen. Normally, I'd hit Windows+D to minimize everything and display the desktop, but that also minimizes the remote desktop session, and the tests I'm running on there (automated web tests through Selenium) start to fail if they detect that the main window does not have focus. Ideally, I'd like to be able to somehow minimize everything and view the desktop just on one display. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Windows natively supports this. You can try the shaking a window method to minimize everything but the current window and do this with the remote desktop window.

Given that you run your remote desktop on a different monitor, I do have a solution that I'm sure off will work as I use it myself (but slightly differently)

There's a program called [dexpot](http://dexpot.de/?id=download), which is a **V**irtual **D**esktop **M**anager. The neat thing about this VDM, is that it has an option to ignore windows on any monitor. This means you can use a shortcut key to move to a different **V**irtual **D**esktop and it does that for all windows on desktop 1, leaving all windows on desktop 2 in tact. It has an option to show  open programs in the taskbar even if the program itself is off-screen, switcing to the right VD when switching to that program.

It also features creating rules to perform automatic actions. These could be: Any application I open, open it on VD1, and jump to VD1. your 2nd VD would then be your clean desktop. Once you start a program from there, it will automatically move it to VD1 and switch there.

Of course, if you're going to use the power of dexpot, you will likely use more VDs and adopt to this system. My desktop is much more tidy now as different programs open in different VDs and they automatically switch to them. It is of course possible to not show the programs in the taskbar (default) so you have to physically navigate to that desktop yourself.

Tiny edit: Dexpot can do a lot more, but I don't want this post to become advertisement. XD This one does what the OP asks for, which is what matters.